# Querying several page fields, some empty

Tags: 2013, search-results, kql

This probably has a very straight-forward answer, but I just can't get my head around it.

I've built a Search Result Web Part checking whether five column on the page are filled out and if so, presents the contents of those five columns.

This is my Query:

```
{Page.Leder 1} OR {Page.Leder 2} OR {Page.Leder 3} OR {Page.Leder 4} OR {Page.Leder 5}
```

It perfectly presents the five results when and ONLY when all five columns are filled out. But if only 4 are filled (ie. one is empty) it returns nothing!

Hope someone with KQL experience can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I digged a great deal more and came up with this Query (partly by chance :o) ).

```
+{?{Page.Leder 1}} OR +{?{Page.Leder 2}} OR +{?{Page.Leder 3}} OR +{?{Page.Leder 4}} OR +{?{Page.Leder 5}}
```

And it Works a charm! This disregards the empty field and presents the fields from eg. Leder 1, Leder 3 and Leder 4.